# Regular Expression to validate if user has provided the correct URI format or not

Tags: javascript, regex, uri

I am trying to write a regular expression or `regex` for my HTML input field with text type. The user should enter the `URI` in the input field. The URI would look something like this: `urn:URNNamespace:**:class:ObjClassid`.

Some of the examples of valid URI are as follows:
urn:abc:testing:pqrs:1234556.1244
urn:wxyz:testing123:abc:1234556.*
urn:global:standard:value:myvalue

I was trying to check only if the initial characters are `URN` using the expression  `^(urn)://` and check if the string contains the character `:` in it.

I just want to make sure that user enters valid URN similar to the one that's provided. Is there any better way I can use and achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a really great tool called [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) that helps you build regular expressions.

I tried to create the described pattern and ended up with:

`^urn:\w+:\w+:\w+:\d+(\.\d+)?$`

[image: Regulex Diagram]

You can try and change it [here](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Eurn%3A%5Cw%2B%3A%5Cw%2B%3A%5Cw%2B%3A%5Cd%2B(%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F%24)